# Impossible to publish an update Google Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an issue while publishing an update on the Google Chrome Web Store.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do you have the same issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue last 12 hours or so!

Comment: not about code. use their issue tracker or superuser forum.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)