# Uploading a new version of a google chrome extension: Lost connection to server

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Today I tried uploading a new version of my Google Chrome extension. While uploading, the site shows "An error occurred: please try again later." and "Lost connection to server"

I'm not sure what information I can give that can help solve this issue, the given error message is not very helpful. Did anyone else get a similar error?

Comment: I've been facing the same issue. Developer console shows the CWS server returning a 503 error.

My guess is that there's something wrong with their servers, and it being the weekend, no one will look at it till Monday.

Comment: @AdiB Ah yeah, hadn't thought of checking the console, glad to see I'm not the only one having the issue. Hope they fix it soon

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Makyen On Google Chrome's documentation, I got linked here under the "help" topic. I assumed it was ok to ask these kinds of questions here, because I found it before I could find anything else regarding support in their documentation.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/best_practices

Comment: @Azeirah, It is not that it is unreasonable to ask a question here it is that the specifics of the question make it off-topic. It is any of A) something that is specific to your setup (in which case we need much more information) and is off-topic without without more information as unclear what you are asking; B) specific to what you were trying to upload, in which case we need an [mcve] and is off-topic without a [mcve]; C) a transitory issue with Google, in which case it will, in the near future, be an issue that we will be unable to reproduce and is/will be off-topic as not reproducible;

Comment: @Azeirah, (continued) or D) asked in a way "Did anyone else get a similar error?" that is more suited to a forum (i.e. a discussion) than Stack Overflow and is off-topic. Asking in a different way might be briefly on-topic (until the issue is fixed by Google and thus off-topic as not reproducible).

Comment: @Azeirah, Or E) a duplicate of [Impossible to publish an update Google Chrome Web Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437491/impossible-to-publish-an-update-google-chrome-web-store) which was posted about 3 hours prior to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error trying to update my extension, but then I tried to change packaging format and I succeeded: upload of zip file including my extensions top folder was ending in failure, but when I created zip file where manifest.json was **top item** in zip file I successfully uploaded it to chrome store. Of course it could be that service got up just at this time.

Comment: I confirm this. Just need to zip the content not the folder. All worked fine.